# UIWebView display and touch area on device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a webview which fills the full screen of the app. The content gets loaded from a web url, and is displayed correctly.

The problem is when I load it in portrait mode and then rotate to landscape, the right side can not receive any touch events. For example, the portrait screen width is 320, when I rotate to landscape which is 480, the right area (width 480-320=160) does not respond to touch. 
The content is always displayed correctly, it fills the whole width, just the touch events don't work. 
If I load it in landscape and then rotate to portrait, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar problem was reported on Apple's developer forum [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/888515#888515)

You should basically add

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
}
```

to the UIWebView's viewcontroller

Comment: This solved my problem. I did try to fix it in a similar way, but I was changing the autoresizingMask on webView and not the parent view and that did't work.